# Gvim shortcut for { }

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, gvim

What is shortcut the moved between `{` and `}` in gvim editor ? how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things to check:

1. make sure loaded_matchparen is enabled.  :let loaded_matchparen = 1
2. If disabled, use `:DoMatchParen` to turn it on.
3. matchparen only works  if 'compatible' is not set.
4. The characters to be matched come from the 'matchpairs' option.  Is it possible this has been overwritten?  The default is `:set matchpairs="(:),{:},[:]"

Try `:help matchparen` to see other things to try.

Last but not least, make sure you hold down that old <kbd>Shift</kbd> Key  when pressing <kbd>5</kbd> (%)  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Put your cursor on one of the braces, and press the `%` key to move to the matching brace.

Comment: no. i am not able do it

Comment: hold shift and press 5?

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html, beyond just `%` you have a couple more options.

1. Use % to jump from an open brace to its matching closing brace. Or from a "#if" to the matching "#endif". Actually, % can jump to many different matching items. It is very useful to check if () and {} constructs are balanced properly.
2. Use [{ to jump back to the "{" at the start of the current code block.
3. Use gd to jump from the use of a variable to its local declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the `%`, which will match parenthesis and braces.